# Positioning of "logo" and "navbar" inside header

Tags: html, css

This is killing me for hours already :'( Can anyone help me to position the logo and navbar inside the header???

I am trying to put the "logo" inside the header (to the left side) and "navbar" inside the header (to the right side) but even though i tried many different properties my navbar is always outside of the header container... Header should be fixed.

http://jsfiddle.net/L7kPu/10/

```
<header>
        <a href="#" id="logo">Logo</a>

                    <ul id="nav" class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>

</header>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

html, body{
  margin:0px; padding:0px; height: 100%; }

section {
    height: 100%;
}

header{
  z-index: 1;
  position:fixed; 
  width:100%;  
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

header ul{
    float:right;

}

header ul li{
    display: inline;
    float:left;

}
header a{
  color:white;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
  display:inline-block; 
  padding:0px 30px; 
  height:60px;
  line-height:60px; 
  text-align:center;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif; 
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform:uppercase; 
  letter-spacing:2px; 
  font-weight:700;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ul` had margin and padding :)

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7kPu/16/)

```
header ul{
    float:right;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header ul li{
    display: inline;
    float:left; 
}
header a{
  color:white;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
  display:inline-block; 
  padding:0px 25px; 
  height:60px;
  line-height:60px; 
  text-align:center;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif; 
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform:uppercase; 
  letter-spacing:2px; 
  font-weight:700;
}
```

I also changed the left and right padding on the `header a` for the sake of the fiddle.

Comment: I was about to answer the same thing!

Comment: Great! Thank you and all others for easing my headache!!! Appreciate it very much!

Comment: No problem! Glad we could help :)

Answer (score 2):

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/derekstory/L7kPu/19/)
Here is the modified css for your code:

```
#logo {
    float: left;
    position: aboslute;
}
#nav {
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
header {
    z-index: 1;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! What does the white-space: nowrap; property do??? Never heard of it...

Comment: That prevents the boxes from "wrapping" aka dropping underneath one another when the width of the page is smaller than the nav width.

Comment: I noticed that the exact thing is happening. But even with 'nowrap' property the same thing happens? Is that a problem if someone is going to browse my page on a small screen devices like cellphones???

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/derekstory/L7kPu/23/ You can add a min-width to the header to prevent the entire nav from dropping as well.

Comment: Great! This is much better, but what is recommended minimum width for today's cellphones? I mean, what min width I should assign in order to keep my header(with logo and navbar) neat and readable on small devices? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: For a mobile I would recommend looking into @media queries so you can customize a menu specifically for those screens. If you aren't designing for mobile, the screen will most likely just shrink to fit. But again, if you expect a mobile audience, consider designing specifically for those screens. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks again! Sure it helps. I will check @media queries even though I am not designing for mobile phones.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
header ul
{
 float:right;
     margin: 0; 
}

header ul li
{
display: inline;
float:left;
margin: 0;
}
```

Also cleaned up your code a little:

http://jsfiddle.net/L7kPu/17/